# how to use sample control for port counters

Tags: performancecounter, sampling, infiniband

I want to monitoring ports in IB fabric.

I happened to notice in the out of perfquery some counter like a ticks and port sampling. Its will be great for accurate monitoring. But I cant found some info about setup and using sampling controi for IB ports.

How to configure and use sampling contol for IB ports? Can anybody give me documentations/links or examples? I cant found it In Google.
Are there any restrictions on the amount of data collected in this sampling mode?

Thanks for you time

Comment: Search for the IB Specification on IBTA site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer.
Its not work in OFED and IB device

Answer - 
"You can read about these counters in the IBA spec volume 1 chapter 16.1
Performance Management which can be obtained from the IBTA web site (even
if your company is not a member, all it requires is a login).

There is support missing in perfquery/libibmad but it wouldn't be hard to
write verbs program to play with this but there were issues with the use of
the sampling counter(s) so AFAIK no one uses them." [http://lists.openfabrics.org/pipermail/users/2016-January/000554.html]